# Efficiently update values in a pandas dataframe with mixed dtype columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large pandas DataFrame with shape (700,000, 5,000) containing columns of mixed dtypes (mostly int8, some float64, and a couple of datetime64[ns]). For each row in the dataframe I want to set the value of certain columns to zero if another column is also equal to zero.

If I iterate over the dataframe and set the values using iloc, it is super slow. I've tried both iterrows and itertuples e.g.

**1. iterrows**

```
ix_1 = 3
ix_to_change = [20, 24, 51]  # Actually it is almost 5000 columns to change
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if not row[ix_1]:
        df.iloc[i, ix_to_change] = 0
```

**2. itertuples:**

```
ix_1 = 3
ix_to_change = [20, 24, 51]  # Actually it is almost 5000 columns to change
for row in df.itertuples():
    if not row[ix_1 + 1]:
        df.iloc[row[0], ix_to_change] = 0
```

I have also tried using pandas indexing, but it is also very slow (though better than iterrows or itertuples).

**3. pandas loc & iloc**

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:, ix_1]==0, df.columns[ix_to_change]] = 0
```

I've then tried dropping down to the underlying numpy array which works fine in terms of performance, but I run into problems with the dtypes.

It quickly iterates through the underlying array, but the new dataframe has all 'object' dtypes. If I try to set the dtypes per column (as in this example) it fails on the datetime columns - possibly because they contain NaT items.

**4. numpy**

```
X = df.values
for i, x in enumerate(X):
    if not x[ix_1]:
        X[i].put(ix_to_change, 0)
original_dtypes = df.dtypes
df = pd.DataFrame(data=X, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
for col, col_dtype in original_dtypes.items():
    df[c] = df[c].astype(col_dtype)
```

Is there a better way for me to make the update in first place?

Or if not, how should I go about keeping my dtypes the same (the datetime columns are not in the list of columns to change in case that is relevant)?

Or maybe there's a better way for me to update the original dataframe with my updated numpy array where I only update the changed columns (all of which are int8)?

#### Update

As requested in the comments, here is a minimal example illustrating how int8 dtypes become object dtypes after dropping into numpy. To be clear, this is only an issue for method 4 above (which is the only non-slow method I have so far - if I can fix this dtype issue):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'int8_col':[10,11,12], 'float64_col':[1.5, 2.5, 3.5]})
df['int8_col'] = df['int8_col'].astype('int8')
df['datetime64_col'] = pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03'])

>>> df.dtypes
float64_col              float64
int8_col                    int8
datetime64_col    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

X = df.values
# At this point in real life I modify the int8 column(s) only in X

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=X, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

>>> new_df.dtypes
float64_col       object
int8_col          object
datetime64_col    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: You may try to use .loc and .iloc with dask dataframe http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html

Comment: OK, so the problem is you're working with `X = df.values`. Don't do this because a single NumPy array can only have one dtype. Internally with Pandas, each series has a separate NumPy array / dtype. You can use Pandas to take advantage of this.

Comment: Thanks @jpp, your point about pandas dataframes being a collection of numpy arrays under the hood (i.e. a collection of columns not rows) was the hint that led me to my solution in Update 2. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Ben, Sure. But you should post your solution as an answer yourself and (if possible) explain what you've done. That way other users can see / vote on it, and you can even accept your own solution.

Comment: Ok yes, moved from the Update 2 to an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses the efficiency of NumPy iteration when updating values and solves the dtype issue as well.

```
# numpy array of rows. Only includes columns to update (all int8) so dtype doesn't change
X = df.iloc[:, ix_to_change].values

# Set index on key to allow enumeration to match index
key_col = df.iloc[:, ix_1]
key_col.index = range(len(key_col))

# Set entire row (~5000 values) to zeros. More efficient than updating element-wise.
zero_row = np.zeros(X.shape[1])
for i, row in enumerate(X):
    if key_col[i] == 0:
        X[i] = zero_row

# Transpose to get array of column arrays.
# Each column array creates and replaces a Series in the DataFrame
for i, row in enumerate(X.T):
    df[df.columns[ix_to_change[i]]] = row
```

X is a NumPy array of only the columns I want to "zero", and they are all int8 dtype.

I iterate over these X rows (much more efficiently here than in pandas), then X.T gives me arrays that I can use to replace entire columns in pandas.

This avoids the slow iloc / loc calls on the big dataframe, and I end up with unchanged dtypes on all columns.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

For Pandas / NumPy efficiency, don't use mixed types (`object` dtype) *within a column*. There are methods available to convert series to numeric and then manipulate them efficiently.

---

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to determine numeric columns. Assuming these are the only ones where you wish to update values, you can then feed these to [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

> It quickly iterates through the underlying array, but the new
>   dataframe has all 'object' dtypes.

Given you are left with `object` dtype series, it seems your definition of `ix_to_change` includes *non-numeric* series. In this case, you should convert all numeric columns to *numeric dtype*. For example, using `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df[ix_to_change] = df[ix_to_change].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Pandas / NumPy will not help with `object` dtype series in terms of performance, if this is what you are after. These series are represented internally as a sequence of pointers, much like `list`.

Here's an example to demonstrate what you can do:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'key': [0, 2, 0, 4, 0],
                   'A': [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5],
                   'B': [2134, 5634, 134, 63, 1234],
                   'C': ['fsaf', 'sdafas',' dsaf', 'sdgf', 'fdsg'],
                   'D': [np.nan, pd.to_datetime('today'), np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'E': [True, False, True, True, False]})

numeric_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns

df.loc[df['key'] == 0, numeric_cols] = 0
```

Result:

```
     A     B       C          D      E  key
0  0.0     0    fsaf        NaT   True    0
1  1.5  5634  sdafas 2018-09-05  False    2
2  0.0     0    dsaf        NaT   True    0
3  3.5    63    sdgf        NaT   True    4
4  0.0     0    fdsg        NaT  False    0
```

No conversion to `object` dtype series for numeric columns, as expected:

```
print(df.dtypes)

A             float64
B               int64
C              object
D      datetime64[ns]
E                bool
key             int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: OP say `have also tried using pandas indexing, but it is also very slow (though better than iterrows or itertuples).

3. pandas loc & iloc

df.loc[df.iloc[:, ix_1]==0, df.columns[ix_to_change]] = 0`

Comment: @jezrael, The problem, I suspect, is with `ix_to_change` definition and resultant `object` dtype columns. The method I've described guarantees you are only working with numeric series. Numeric series with dtype object should be converted to numeric first. This should then be efficient.

Comment: it depends of  real data, OP decide best how working it with real data ;)

Comment: @jezrael, Yep, I've added more description. Clearly, if OP is *left* with `object` dtype series, as described, it's going to be inefficient. The best way is to convert to numeric first.

Comment: ya, I am afraid if OP want set all rows, numeric and also non numeric :(

Comment: FYI in my real case all columns in ix_to_change are int8. My "3. pandas loc & iloc" method is effectively the same as this numeric method, and is unfortunately still super slow. The dtype issue only comes up in the numpy method, where it actually runs very fast but I end up with object dtypes that would need converting back to the original dtypes once I wrap the numpy array in a new pandas dataframe.

Comment: @Ben, If that's true, then you shouldn't get "all columns converted to `object`" at the end. I suggest you add a minimal example showing this exactly happens. Because, right now, I refuse to believe an `int` series becomes `object` after converting some values to `0`.

Comment: Added minimal example to illustrate how int8 series become object

Comment: OK, so the problem is you're working with `X = df.values`. Don't do this because a single NumPy array can only have one dtype. Internally with Pandas, each series has a separate NumPy array / dtype. You can use Pandas to take advantage of this.